# PermissionError in Images from PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm making a bing image scraper and saving them to a directory within the project folder, but when it runs the `.save()` Pillow is returning this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './scraped_images/'`

The following is my code, using Pyhton3.7 and Pillow5.3.0

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


search = input("Search for: ")
params = {"q": search}
r = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/images/search", params=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "thumb"})

for item in links:
    img_obj = requests.get(item.attrs["href"])
    title = item.attrs["href"].split("/")[-1]
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(img_obj.content))
    img.save("./scraped_images/", img.format)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have write permissions to that directory... You're also passing the directory for the filename... See the documentaton here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Comment: @Pythonista yes i do have write permission to that directory, i added the `title` variable into the `img.save("./scraped_images/" + title, img.format)` and it worked on 5 pictures, then it gave me another error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './scraped_images/sharing.jpg?w=738'`

Comment: Yeah because that's not valid. You cant have certain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the directory for the filename... See the documentation here pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html

Make sure the filenames you have are also valid or you'll also get an error. The name itself should not have any excluded characters and follow standard conventions and end with a valid image extension.